# JQGrid TreeGrid Client side on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jqgrid, treegrid

I am facing a performance problem(script running too long)in IE8 while working on jqgrid treegrid. I have around 1000 records, everything is on client side.

is there any way to load child records on demand. Here I need to do everything on client side.

Please suggest me any solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here everything is local. I am using JSON as data format. Due to performance issue i want to load child nodes on demand intead of loading all at a time. I am using this link for sample - http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/treegrid.html

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? Are all 1000 records direct children of one node of the grid? Do you you `loaded: true` property for all loaded items? If you dons set `loaded: true` properties in the server response then the children will be loaded on demand: when the user expand the tree node.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, load on demand works fine with client - server interaction. But here everything i have on client side. So how can I do load on demand for client side data. Means initially I want to parse only parent nodes after that click on parent should load childs on demand. I am using jqgrid 4.4.3 version.